# Unwanted Shimmering Effect with 1D Texture on Lines

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, texture1d

I am trying to apply 1D texture to lines. It works but lines shimmer. I don't want this shimmering effect. Like on the picture.

[image: Shimmering Problem]

I've also added a video about shimmering problem:

[Shimmering Problem Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByJDypWl2oFiekxSUjAtSUM2U00/view)

How can I solve this problem? I am adding the codes below.

**Vertex Shader:**

```
attribute vec4 vertexMC;
uniform mat4 MCVCMatrix;
uniform mat4 VCDCMatrix;
attribute float tcoordMC;
varying float tcoordVC;
void main()
{
    tcoordVC=(vertexMC.x+vertexMC.y+vertexMC.z)/3.0;
    gl_Position=VCDCMatrix*MCVCMatrix*vertexMC;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
varying float tcoordVC;
uniform sampler1D texture1;
uniform vec3 GridColor;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=vec4(GridColor, texture1D(texture1,tcoordVC).a);
    if (gl_FragColor.a <= 0.0) discard;
}
```

**Texture:**

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

unsigned char buf[ 16 * 4 ];
for( size_t i=0; i < sizeof( buf ); i+=4 )
{
    buf[ i+0 ]=255;
    buf[ i+1 ]=0;
    buf[ i+2 ]=0;
}

buf[3]= 255;
buf[7]= 0;
buf[11]=255;
buf[15]=0;
buf[19]=255;
buf[23]=0;
buf[27]=255;
buf[31]=0;
buf[35]=255;
buf[39]=0;
buf[43]=255;
buf[47]=0;
buf[51]=255;
buf[55]=0;
buf[59]=255;
buf[63]=0;

glTexImage1D( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 4, sizeof( buf ) / 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf );
InternalShader->Program.SetUniformi("texture1",1);
```

**Draw Section:**

```
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_1D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);

for(unsigned int i=0;i<GridsInternal.size();i++)
{        
    AGrid=GridsInternal[i];

    if(!AGrid->GetActivity())
        continue;

    ACellBO=CellBOs[i];
    AVBO=VBOs[i];
    ALayout=Layouts[i];

    AVBO->Bind();

    SetMapperShaderParameters(i);
    SetPropertyShaderParameters(i);
    ACellBO->ibo.Bind();

    glDrawRangeElements(GL_LINES, 0,
                        static_cast<GLuint>(ALayout->VertexCount-1),
                        static_cast<GLsizei>(ACellBO->indexCount),
                        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                        reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid *>(NULL));

    AVBO->Release();
    ACellBO->ibo.Release();
    ACellBO->vao.Release();
}

glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
```

Comment: Does it look any better with `GL_LINEAR` instead of `GL_NEAREST`?

Comment: @genpfault still same and its shimmering when I move the camera

Comment: @VeyselBekirMacit seems like the normal aliasing effect. Maybe try `glEnable( GL_MULTISAMPLE )` or other anti-aliasing techniques

Comment: @PeterT, Anti-Aliasing doesn't help I added GL_LINE_SMOOTH and glLineWidth() still same it's effect like GL_LINEAR. I just want dashed lines without shimmering. Also there is a function in opengl gllinestipple() it shimmers,too.

Comment: Mip Mapping of some sort might fix this, too.

Comment: @Krythic I heard this mip mapping how can it be applied to 1D texture? I have tried GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR but with it opengl draws without dashed just normal line?